# Accessing non-Python files from another package in PEP518 environment (pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I want to make a Python package (from here on `mypackage`) which includes non-Python files (in my case, these are C++ header files) that are to be made available during installation of other packages which use it as a dependency (from here on `other_package`).

In order for `mypackage` to include the files in source distributions and make the same files installable, I did the following:

- Included the files in the `MANIFEST.in` package file:

```
graft <folder_with_files>
```

- Included the files in the `setup.py` file under `data_files`.

```py
setup(
    name = 'mypackage',
    packages = ['mypackage'],
    ...
    data_files = ["folder_path", ("the", "files")]
)
```

So far, having them in both places makes `mypackage` correctly install with the non-Python files included when using `distutils`, `setuptools`, or `pip` (both local and from PyPI). When using `setuptools` and `pip`, I can then find the non-Python files under `folder_path` in `sys.prefix` - e.g.:

```py
import sys, os
os.path.join(sys.prefix, "folder_path")
```

And when using `distutils`, they are under the same folder as the python files, thus they can be found through `mypackage.__file__` - e.g.

```py
import re, mypackage
re.sub(r"__init__\.py$", "", mypackage.__file__) + "folder_path"
```

But here's the issue: when another package that uses this as a dependency has this dependency specified through PEP518 with a `pyproject.toml` file, `mypackage` is downloaded from PyPI, and installed in the temporary environment that PEP518 generates, but the non-Python files are NOT under `sys.prefix` - rather, they install under some randomly-named temporary folder like this:

```
$TEMP_FOLDER/pip-build-env-otci9gxx/overlay/folder_path
```

Thus, my script that tries to find the files under `sys.prefix` or `mypackage.__file__`'s root doesn't pick those files.

How can I programatically and deterministically get the path into which those files are installed in the PEP518 environment from the `setup.py` of `other_package`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want to use `data_files`?

I would recommend using `package_data` instead. This way files are part of the Python *package* itself (installed in `site-packages` for example) and are very easy to retrieve once installed.

**Resources**:

- https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files
- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#package-data

Access the installed *package data* with either one of those:

**1.** [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data)

```
import pkgutil
pkgutil.get_data('my_top_level_package.my_sub_package', 'file.bin')
```

**2.** [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.read_binary)

```
importlib.resources.read_binary('my_top_level_package.my_sub_package', 'file.bin')
```

**3.** [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api)